# Div tag inside td does not showing background color on mozilla

Tags: css, html, web

My goal is to draw bar chart and everything looks fine on Google Chrome but on Mozilla Firefox(v 46.0.1) div's tag inside td element do not display background color at all.
Here's live example:  https://jsfiddle.net/zck5mw7m/
Green bar does not show up in Mozilla Firefox but it does in Google Chrome

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: initial;
  z-index: 3;

  > div {
    background: #72a822;
    margin: 0 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Label</p>
        <div ng-style="{'height': order.value/maxValue * 100 + '%'}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT 
Originally I calculated and set height property of div element using angularjs dynamically. I remind that this code works for Google chrome but IT DOEST NOT work for Mozilla Firefox so the problem lays somewhere in compatibility of browsers.

EDIT vol 2

Here's live example:  https://jsfiddle.net/zck5mw7m/
Green bar does not show up in Mozilla Firefox but it does in Google Chrome

Comment: `height: 75%;` is `75%` of `auto` which is `auto` which is `0`. The div has a background colour. You misinterpreted the problem.

Comment: "Here's css" — That looks like SCSS to me. It certainly isn't valid CSS.

Comment: No I did not misinterpreted the problem. I simplified code by reducing angular's directive to make it more readable and one of such simplification was to move dynamically calculated height property to be static in scss it was my mistake and I corrected it.

Comment: @Quentin Moreover I do not agree that it is duplicated question because as I initially wrote it works and properly display on Chrome and it does not display on mozilla.

Comment: Then you need to provide a real [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. At the moment your live demo features SCSS being treated as CSS (so it doesn't work) and Angular templating code being treated as HTML (so it doesn't work).

Comment: When you said "mozilla" do you mean "Firefox, the browser currently supported by Mozilla" or "Mozilla Suite, the browser that Mozilla used to make but abandoned years ago"? (You called Chrome, "Chrome" and not "Google").

Comment: @Quentin I've added live example in jsfiddle and precise browsers versions.

Comment: Don't hide your examples on another site. Put them in the question.

Comment: … and I've tested it by adding a height to the td. It is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

use what is called inline css.

```
<td style="background-color: #E30000;">this is a Test </td>
```

This should work for you.

Comment: The question is asking about changing the background colour of the **div** not the **td**.

Comment: Use of the style attribute is almost always a terrible idea, and almost always only a solution to the problem "I don't know how to use selectors" (which isn't the case here).

Comment: Yeah this will work but I want to have td element as container which includes <p> Label</p> and <div></div> which will present by its height percentage value.